# Parsing multi-format & multi line data file in spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch job to process the below mentioned data file and write it into a db.

- Sample data file is of this format where I have multiple headers and
  each header has a bunch of rows associated with it .
- I can have million of records for each header and I can have n number
  of headers in a flat file that am processing.My requirement is to
  pick a few readers which am concerned .
- For all the picked readers I need to pick all the data rows .Each
  header and its data format is also different .I can receive either of
  these data in my processor and need to write them into my DB.

### HDR01

A|41|57|Data1|S|62|Data2|9|N|2017-02-01 18:01:05|2017-02-01 00:00:00
A|41|57|Data1|S|62|Data2|9|N|2017-02-01 18:01:05|2017-02-01 00:00:00

### HDR02

A|41|57|Data1|S|62|Data2|9|N|
A|41|57|Data1|S|62|Data2|9|N|

- I tried exploring the PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper where I can
  map the different header pattern I have to a tokenizer and
  corresponding FieldSetMapper but I need to read the body and not the
  header here .
- Don't have any footer to Crete a end of line policy of my own as well .
- Also tried using AggregateItemReader but don't want to club all the
  records of a header before I process them .
- Each rows corresponding a header should be processed parallel .

  @Bean
  public LineMapper myLineMapper() {

  ```
  PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper< Domain > mapper = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<>();
  final Map<String, LineTokenizer> tokenizers = new HashMap<String, LineTokenizer>();
  tokenizers.put("* HDR01*", new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
  tokenizers.put("*HDR02*", new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
  tokenizers.put("*", new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|"));
  mapper.setTokenizers(tokenizers);

  Map<String, FieldSetMapper<VMSFeedStyleInfo>> mappers = new HashMap<String, FieldSetMapper<VMSFeedStyleInfo>>();
  try {
      mappers.put("* HDR01*", customMapper());
      mappers.put("*HDR02*", customMapper());
      mappers.put("*", customMapper() );
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  mapper.setFieldSetMappers(mappers);

  return mapper;
  ```

  }

Can somebody help me provide some inputs as to how should I achieve this .

Comment: Could you have a tasklet to split the main file to multiple files (each contains a header with data) and then perform partition for the processing?

Comment: @NghiaDo For my batch job ,I have a mount which has bunch of these files and the partitioning is the first step where 1 data file file per partition is run .

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: @ Nghia Do -my first step in my job involves partitioning of data files present in my mount folder .I can have hundreds of these data files in a mount location which am partitioning .When you say we can write a task let to split a text file ,do you have any references to take a look .

Comment: If so, that is totally fit with the approach. You can have a split logic in partitions for Reader (Read a big file) , Processor (Split), Writer (Write to multiple files)